# On including the PDF file getting no such file or directory error while running Test Case in React js

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

**Nothing to do with components as seen in other StackOverflow questions, this is related PDF files**

When I am running this code I am getting the desired result.

````
import { Row, Col, Footer, Icon, Modal, Button } from 'xps-react';
import pdf from '../../assets/pdf/pdfDummy.pdf';```
````

But when running the test case the same code gives error "ENOENT: no such file or directory" as you can see below:

testing...
FAIL  **test**/components/AppFooter/AppFooter.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/../../assets/pdf/pdfDummy.pdf'

  1 | import React, { Component } from 'react';
  2 | import { Row, Col, Footer, Icon, Modal, Button } from 'xps-react';
> 3 | import pdf from '/../../assets/pdf/pdfDummy.pdf';
```

```
The code is running fine, and even the build is running fine. I am only getting an error when trying to run test cases on this file.
```

Comment: where is your pdf file in relation to your test file?

Comment: The PDF is a static file for terms and conditions. I open it when user clicks the link. The same is running fine with code. Now when I test the same code, it gives me error for the PDF file "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/../../assets/pdf/pdfDummy.pdf'"